# How can I initialize low-precision geolocation under React Native for iOS?

Tags: ios, geolocation, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, reactjs-native

My code has, in the React.createClass() call:

```
  watchID: (null: ?number),
  componentDidMount: function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (initialPosition) => this.setState({initialPosition}),
      (error) => console.error(error),
      (position) => this.setState({position}),
      {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 60 * 60 * 1000});
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((lastPosition) =>
      this.setState({lastPosition}));
  },
```

This is generating the error message `Argument 0 (RCTLocationOptions of RCTLocationObserver.getCurrentPosition must not be null`.

Is there a problem with the initialPosition arrow function? Also, how can I replace the initialPosition argument with an appropriate anonymous function that will set the initial position to both the initial and last position (being both the initial and the last position), and call a `this.fetchData()`?

(Feel free to explain anything I'm missing about arrow functions...)

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like the you are not passing the arguments in the the right order? I'm not familiar with react native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Geolocation/RCTLocationObserver.m#L194-L196

Answer (score 0):

The third argument, `(position) => this.setState({position}),` was the culprit. It expected a (possibly optional AFAIK) hash of options in that spot.